# How do I import an external library into Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to use the commons-codec-1.9.jar from the commons-codec-1.9 library supplied by Apache. I've used this as a library in another project in NetBeans, so I already had the required .jar file that I needed to import. I copied the jar file from the NetBeans project and put it in my app project (app:libs folder) and right-clicked and chose the "Add as library..." option. I added it to my project dependencies as well via File > Project Structure > Dependencies. I created the import for the library in the classes I've written that use the library, and I get no errors and the code builds. However, when I run the app, it breaks and throws a NoSuchMethod exception... even though it is there.

Here are the contents of my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.<path_stuff>"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
}
```

Here is my settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
```

I have also recently been getting a build error after I removed the commons-codec stuff from the libs folder and tried to re-add it. The error says something along the lines of "Build failed: could not find task 'assemble' in project " as if Android Studio thinks this is another project. Can someone please help me understand what is going on here and where I am going wrong?

No such method error details:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String
```

**Edit:** Realized I included the incorrect build.gradle file. Updated settings.gradle to remove the include statement. Included correct build.gradle and NoSuchMethod error.

Comment: Including it via settings.gradle is incorrect. The way most projects are set up, just dropping it in the **libs** directory in your module is sufficient since there's a build rule to automatically pick up all jars placed there. Can we see your module's build.gradle file as well as the full details of the NoSuchMethod exception you're getting? Additionally, you should consider upgrading to Android Studio 1.0.

Comment: My build.gradle file is already there (above the settings.gradle block). I have since removed the .jars causing the problem but I will try to replicate.

Comment: You've got another, more important build.gradle file in your module's root directory.

Comment: It's there now, my apologies.

Comment: Get rid of the duplication in your `dependencies`, as that won't help. Either include all the JARs or only the one JAR; do not try to do both. You might also consider using the `commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9` artifact, rather than a local JAR: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9

Answer (score 0):

Remove `include ':libs:commons-codec-1.9:` from your `settings.gradle`.

Add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')` to your dependencies block in your module's `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

This will automatically compile any `.jar` file in your `libs` folder into your project.